# Why does pandas Series.str convert numbers to NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

This might be a fundamental misunderstanding on my part, but I would expect `pandas.Series.str` to convert the `pandas.Series` values into strings.

However, when I do the following, numeric values in the series are converted to `np.nan`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo    ', 'bar', 42]})
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == 'object' else x)
print(df)

Out:
     a
0  foo
1  bar
2  NaN
```

If I apply the `str` function to each column first, numeric values are converted to strings instead of `np.nan`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo    ', 'bar', 42]})
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(str) if x.dtype == 'object' else x)
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == 'object' else x)
print(df)

Out:
     a
0  foo
1  bar
2   42
```

The documentation is fairly scant on this topic. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == 'object' else x)
```

The `x.dtype` is looking at the entire Series (column). The column is not numeric.  Thus the entire column is operated on like strings.

In your second example, the number is not preserved, it is a string `'42'`.

The difference in the output will be due to the difference in panda's str and python's str.

In the case of pandas `.str`, this is not a conversion, it is an accessor, that allows you to do the `.strip()` to each element.  What this means is that you attempt to apply `.strip()` to an integer.  This throws an exception, and pandas responds to the exception by returning Nan.

In the case of `.apply(str)`, you are actually converting the values to a string.  Later when you apply `.strip()` this succeeds, since the value is already a string, and thus can be stripped.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are using `.apply` is by *columns*, so note while:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == 'object' else x)
     a
0  foo
1  bar
2  NaN
```

It acted on the column, `x.dtype` was *always* `object`.

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x:x.dtype)
a    object
dtype: object
```

If you did go by row, using `axis=1`, you'd still see the same behavior:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x:x.dtype, axis=1)
0    object
1    object
2    object
dtype: object
```

Lo and behold:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype == 'object' else x, axis=1)
     a
0  foo
1  bar
2  NaN
>>>
```

So, when it says `object` dtype, it means *Python `object`*. So consider a non-object numeric column:

```
>>> S = pd.Series([1,2,3])
>>> S.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> S[0]
1
>>> S[0].dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> isinstance(S[0], int)
False
```

Whereas with this object dtype column:

```
>>> df
         a
0  foo
1      bar
2       42
>>> df['a'][2]
42
>>> isinstance(df['a'][2], int)
True
>>>
```

You Are effectively doing this:

```
>>> s = df.a.astype(str).str.strip()
>>> s
0    foo
1    bar
2     42
Name: a, dtype: object
>>> s[2]
'42'
```

Note:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(str) if x.dtype == 'object' else x).a[2]
'42'
```